# plot gmdistribution.fit together with data

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, gaussian

I have a histogram of data (x,y) which is a mixed of two Gaussians (simple case i.e in one dimension). To get a fit to it, i use

obj= gmdistribution.fit(data,2)

that gives me the

obj =

Gaussian mixture distribution with 2 components in 1 dimensions
Component 1:
Mixing proportion: 0.499387
Mean:    -0.4789

Component 2:
Mixing proportion: 0.500613
Mean:    -0.4786

Now, how can I plot this together with the original histogram? I am aware of these 2 links but they dont help me so much:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/317868

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/stats/gmdistribution.fit.html

Any clear help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I guess this might be a bit late, but its been updated on matlabs [site](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/stats/gmdistribution.fit.html). Just in case

```
MU1 = [1 2];
SIGMA1 = [2 0; 0 .5];
MU2 = [-3 -5];
SIGMA2 = [1 0; 0 1];
X = [mvnrnd(MU1,SIGMA1,1000);mvnrnd(MU2,SIGMA2,1000)];

scatter(X(:,1),X(:,2),10,'.')
hold on

options = statset('Display','final');
obj = gmdistribution.fit(X,2,'Options',options);
10 iterations, log-likelihood = -7046.78

h = ezcontour(@(x,y)pdf(obj,[x y]),[-8 6],[-8 6]);
```

You could do the same for 3d using scatter3.

[image]

[image]